# Расширенная параметризация классов Java

Tags: java, java-8

Задача сделать так чтобы класс `Conteiner` был параметризован только типом `<Car>` и `<Bike>` и их потомками, знаю что можно создать их общий супер класс или интерфейс, но лучший ли это способ или есть варианты по лучше

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       Container<Car.Sedan> sedans;
       Container<Bike.Scooter> scooters;
   }
}
class Container<T extends Car | Bike> {}  // ошибка

class Car {
   class Sedan extends Car {}
   class Pickup extends Car {}
   class Truck extends Car {}
}
class Bike {
   class Bicycle extends Bike {}
   class Scooter extends Bike {}
   class Motorcycle extends Bike {}
}
```

Comment: А зачем это нужно? Как вы планируете работать с `T`, который "то ли Car, то ли Bike"? Если у них есть одинаковые методы/поля - нужно выделять их в супер класс. Если у них нет одинаковых методов/полей - с таким же успехом можно принимать просто абстрактное `T` (или вообще не использовать `T` - работать с `object`) - на функционал Container-а это не повлияет

Comment: У них есть супер класс Transport но от нее возможно будут наследоваться и другие классы которые не должны дженерить Container, остается только создавать абстрактный класс или интерфейс только для того чтобы можно было их абстрактно обьединить чтобы использовать как параметр?

Comment: Да, создать абстрактный класс или интерфейс. А почему другие наследники Transport не подходят?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Желаемый вариант записи `<T extends Car | Bike>` с использованием оператора ИЛИ `|` является синтаксической ошибкой, в Java можно применять дополнительные ограничения на обобщённый класс при [помощи И `&`](https://web.archive.org/web/20081217141004/http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html), поэтому в данном случае возможны такие варианты:

- создать некий общий класс для `Car` и `Bike`:

```
class Common extends Transport {}
class Container<T extends Common> {}
class Car extends Common {}
class Bike extends Common {}
```

- создать маркерный интерфейс для объектов в контейнере, тогда классы `Car` и `Bike` необязательно должны порождаться от класса `Transport`

```java
interface Containable {}
class Container<T extends Containable> {}
class Car implements Containable {}
class Bike implements Containable {}
```

- создать спецконтейнер для потомков `Transport`, реализующих интерфейс `Containable`:

```java
interface Containable {}
class Container<T extends Transport & Containable> {}
class Car extends Transport implements Containable {}
class Bike extends Transport implements Containable {}
```